# Linking.openUrl not working with urls containing non english characters

Tags: react-native

I am using Linking from React-Native. Linking.OpenUrl seems to work with most urls but it does not seem to work with urls which have non-english characters. See the example below in Expo where I have reproduced the case. Note that if you click on the url link directly it will open properly. However, when the same link is being opened via the Linking.OpenUrl it does something to the url and lands in a 404 page.

Here is a repro in Expo:
https://snack.expo.dev/@rezahok/linking-not-working

I am using Expo 42. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const uri = `https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%9C%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%82%E0%A7%9F%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%A4-%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9C%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%9F%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B0-%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE-%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%A4-%E0%A7%A9`
    const decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(uri);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title="Click me" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL(decodedUri)}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and this does not resolve the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: From your expo url , it seems working.